# Publish files from Team Foundation Service to an Azure Cloud Storage Blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-devops

Is it possible to automatically publish (static) files from Team Foundation Service to an Azure Cloud Storage Blob during build?

UPDATE:
If it isn't possible to publish *directly* to a blob, perhaps there is a good workaround to publish *indirectly*? I also publish another project to an azure website, so one way is to publish the files to that website and then using [WebActivator](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator) I can move the files to the blob at first activation. But I hope for a better solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you would need to be able to customize the build process in order to do that, and that customization is something I don't believe you can do today with Team Foundation Service.  If using Team Foundation Server, then yes.

Comment: I _think_ you are right that it isn't possible to do this _directly_. I'm also interested in an _indirect_ way to achieve this, so I updated my question.